# How to fix multiple forms problem (CS7036)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that sends information from two forms (Form 2 to Form 1) and I have a menu screen that enters Form 2 but when I try to open form two I get the error (CS7036). Basically, I have the error that says

> "Error    CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'incoming' of 'difficulty.difficulty(Easy)"

(difficulty is "form 2" and easy is "form 1"

FROM Menu

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    difficulty diff = new difficulty();
    diff.ShowDialog();
}
```

FROM DIFFICULTY

```
public partial class difficulty : Form
{

    public difficulty(Easy incoming) 
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEasy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Easy easy = new Easy();
        easy.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

How do I make it work so I can enter the menu then difficulty then easy without any errors? Any help appreciated.

Comment: In `difficulty diff = new difficulty();` you'll have to pass the instance of the `Easy` Form: `difficulty diff = new difficulty([easy_instance]);`. But, in `this.Close()`, what is `this`? And how are you using, having `Easy original;` the `original` reference?

Comment: You're creating an instance of difficulty using a constructor that is supposed to receive a parameter of type Easy "incoming". Try passing a value when instantiating difficulty: `difficulty diff = new difficulty(value);`

Comment: Do you use somewhere the _incoming_ instance declared in the constructor of _difficulty_?

Comment: @Jimi do i just add in the "[easy_instance]" because it didn't work (sorry I'm a beginner)

Comment: @CarlosParra what kind of value do i add (I'm new to this)

Comment: Your `btnEasy` click handler is almost certainly wrong.  Since you displayed `diff` with `ShowDialog()` from the Menu, control will return back to it when you use `this.Close();` in `difficulty`.  Creating a new instance of `Easy` is probably not what you need to do.  It might not be "certainly wrong"...but you definitely need to explain better what is happening and how the program/information needs to flow.

Comment: Probably have to take a step back.  Why does the Difficulty form need to have an Easy form to do anything?

Comment: Do you have, in `btnStart`, an instance of `Easy` available? If yes, then pass that instance. As already asked, in `this.Close()`, what is `this`?

Comment: @Jimi I dont, and this.Close() is supposed to close the current windowsform

Comment: @Idle_Mind Not sure if it's useful but I'm doing a menu form where i click I'm supposed to click start so the menu closes then go to difficulty then I'm supposed to have 3 options for "Difficulties" to choose from, Also do you know a better solution then "this.Close()"

Comment: I know what `.Close()` does. I asked what `this` is referencing. What is the Form that you're closing? + If you don't always have an instance of `Easy`, add an empty constuctor to `difficulty`: `public difficulty() : this(null) { }`, so you can instantiate it without passing anything. As already asked, do you really need to pass an instance of `Easy` to `difficulty`. You're creating an instance of it anyway in `btnEasy`, without using the `original` reference.

Comment: @Jimi I need the instance of Easy in difficulty because i am trying to pass information of RadioButton in difficulty to easy, also "this.Close()" is me trying to close the menu. what is this "difficulty: public difficulty() : this(null) { }" because i need the instance of easy

Comment: I asked before *Do you have, in `btnStart`, an instance of `Easy` available?*. You answered: *I don't*. Now, I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: @Jimi you said if i had an instance of easy i should add "difficulty: public difficulty() : this(null) { }" do i add it on the difficulty form on "public difficulty(Easy incoming)", sorry im new to this so i have a hard time understanding.

Comment: If you need an instance of `Easy` (with the properties/values it holds) in `difficulty`, the instance of `Easy` must exist at that point. Use it to reference it. Do not create another one. Also, about this, why do you have code in `difficulty` that tries to create an instance of Easy: `Easy easy = new Easy();` when, as you said, such instance (the one that you need) already exists?. Pass it to the new instance of `difficulty` and use it. It's the `original` reference. The empty constructor you can add it and leave it there. In WinForms, you should always have an empty constructor.

Comment: @Jimi the "difficulty: public difficulty() : this(null) { }" code did work and removed all errors but now when i click Start the entire program closes. Also what did you mean by the one instance that i needed already existed which one were you refeering to?

Comment: `Easy` is the name of a class. A class that builds a Form. With `Easy instance_of_easy = new Easy();`, you create an instance of that class. With this: `instance_of_easy.ShowDialog();` you show that instance, creating a Form object. Well, you need to have an instance of `Easy` already created to pass it to your `difficulty` Form. Here: `public difficulty(Easy incoming)`, you're passing an existing instance of `Easy` to `difficulty`. Assign `incoming` to a Field and use it to reference the existing instance of `Easy`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed in the parameter you added to your constructor while instantiating the class.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    //use whatever easy you have here
    Easy easy = new Easy();
    difficulty diff = new difficulty(easy); 
    diff.ShowDialog(); 

    this.Hide();
}
```

You need to have an `Easy` class created beforehand to pass in. And if you want to use that instance in the class, you can do this:

```
public partial class difficulty : Form { 

    private Easy easy;
    public difficulty(Easy incoming) 
    { 
        easy = incoming;
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    private void btnEasy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
          ....
    } 
}
```

Then in any of the class functions, reference the `easy` variable to get data.

Comment: This won't work as expected.  Please see comments above.  Several are very good comments on how to accomplish this.